# How can I determine which edges are part of simple paths between a vertex subset?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

### Problem:

- I have an **undirected graph** (with cycles) given by a list of edges.
- I'm given a list/subset of vertices/nodes *(example: [0, 9, 17] below)*, which I refer to as "**important vertices**".
- I want to color each **edge** based on whether it is part of some **simple path** [1] between the important vertices.  In the example below, I have colored the edges red if they are part of such a simple path, and blue otherwise.

[image: Visualization of coloring result]

[1]: *a simple path means any vertex can appear at most once in the path*.

### Questions:

- Does this problem have a name?
- Are there any existing algorithms that solve this problem?
- What is the optimal time comlexity? *My gut feeling tells me it might be possible to solve this by visiting every edge a constant number of times. Once you know whether an edge is part of a simple path or not, you probably don't need to visit it again.*

### What I've tried so far:

- For every edge, perform a depth-first search in both directions to find out which **important vertices** are reachable through simple paths in both directions.
- If either of the directions don't reach an important vertex, or only the single and same important vertex is reached in both directions, the edge will color itself blue - otherwise it will color itself red.
- This *almost* works - but mistakenly colors the 15-16 edge red - and seems to scale really poorly, which is why I'm looking for a better way to do this.

### Related:

- [How to find if there is a simple path from vertex x to vertex y that includes the edge e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70571584/how-to-find-if-there-is-a-simple-path-from-vertex-x-to-vertex-y-that-includes-th)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104849/find-edges-part-of-a-simple-path-between-two-vertices

*I don't consider this question to be a duplicate of the above, since this is about an **arbitrary number** of "important vertices", and about classifying **all edges**, rather than a single one.*

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118516/finding-all-edges-that-appear-on-at-least-one-s-t-path/72397637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want yo find [biconnected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component). They form a tree (forest if the graph is not connected; in this case handle each tree separately). Then colour some edges and vertices of that tree red.

Articulation vertices of the original graph correspond to tree vertices, and biconnected subgraphs correspond to tree edges.

If an important vertex is an articulation vertex, colour it red.

If a biconnected component has any important vertices which are not articulation vertices, colour the corresponding tree edge and both its vertices red.

If there is a path between two red vertices of the tree, colour the entire path (edges and vertices) red.

Repeat until there is no more edges or vertices to colour.

There seems to be a single exceptional case in the algorithm above, namely when there is a single important vertex in a (simply connected) component. It is easy to detect and handle separately.

Comment: This is a better run-time than my solution; I think biconnected components are exactly what OP wanted.

Comment: I guess I'd want to first calculate **connected components**, and then pick any starting point for **biconnected component** search within each such connectivity island? (since my graph is not guaranteed to be connected)

Comment: Not sure you need to calculate connected components separately. Just start doing a biconnected component search. If the algo ends without visiting all the vertices, you have a non-connected graph. Start again with an unvisited vertex.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your graph is connected, start with any [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree#Algorithms) in blue. There will be one path through all of the important vertices, re-colour this red.

[image: Example graph.]

Any uncoloured edge forms a loop. If a loop has any edges that are red, re-colour it red, including the uncoloured edge. Go repeatedly through all the uncoloured edges until you cannot colour a loop red. Then, colour the remaining edges blue.

[image: Complete.]

I think this works; because the red edges are necessarily connected.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. What if there is an edge between 5 and 13?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Good catch. I think I've fixed it.

Comment: Although this one is significantly slower.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out this problem becomes simpler if I focus on which vertices are part of simple paths, rather than edges. I'll name these "connecting vertices". Any edge with a "connecting vertex" in each end is part of some simple path between important vertices.

*(with the exception of edges with the same vertex in both ends. This type of edge will never be part of any simple path)*

I ended up with an algorithm which is similar to biconnected components, but different in what it tracks as it traverses the trees/forest. I believe it has linear time complexity (`O(V+E)`).

I've implemented it in Python/numpy below as a depth-first search.

```py
import numpy as np

def is_connecting_vertex(get_neighbors, important_vertices, vertex_count):
    visited = np.zeros(vertex_count, dtype='bool')
    parent = np.zeros(vertex_count, dtype='int64')
    last_important = np.zeros(vertex_count, dtype='int64')
    is_important = np.zeros(vertex_count, dtype='bool')
    is_connecting = np.zeros(vertex_count, dtype='bool')
    
    stack = []
    for v in important_vertices:
        parent[v] = v
        last_important[v] = v
        is_important[v] = True
        is_connecting[v] = True
        stack.append(v)
    
    while len(stack):
        v = stack.pop()
        if visited[v]:
            continue
        visited[v] = True

        if is_important[v]:
            p = parent[v]
            while not is_connecting[p]:
                is_connecting[p] = True
                p = parent[p]
        else:
            last_important[v] = last_important[parent[v]]

        for child in get_neighbors(v):
            if not visited[child]:
                parent[child] = v
                stack.append(child)
            elif last_important[child] != last_important[v]:
                is_connecting[v] = True
                p = parent[v]
                while not is_connecting[p]:
                    is_connecting[p] = True
                    p = parent[p]
    
    return is_connecting
```

Thanks to both `n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.` and `Neil` for putting me on the right track with their answers.

Comment: By "connecting vertex" you mean the same thing as cut vertex/articulation points? That is impressive, but I have trouble seeing what `last_important` is.

Comment: No, removing a "connecting vertex" won't necessarily cause the graph to become disconnected. For example vertex 3 in the example is a "connecting vertex", but is not a cut vertex/articulation point. 0,1,3,6,7,8,9,11,17 are "connecting vertices" in my example.

Comment: Regarding `last_important` - it keeps track of the previous ancestor of each vertex in the DFS which was an important vertex. The point being that if you find an edge that causes `last_important` to change, you have just discovered a simple path between 2 important vertices - and so all vertices on that path can be marked as being "connecting vertices". This includes when you discover backlinks to an important vertex which is different from the current `last_important`.